# Eclipse: project directory isolated from source directory

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Java code managed by a Git repository. Currently, the directory structure is

```
myProject    | 
    -- src
    -- bin
    -- lib
    -- .git
```

Currently, each developer creates its own development environment under his desired tool (Eclipse/Netbeans). I would like to create a Eclipse project for this code and add it to my source repository, so that new Eclipse developers don't need to create a new project and set the dev environment manually. I'd like to have this:

```
myProject
   | 
    -- src
    -- bin
    -- lib
    -- .git
    -- eclipse
     |
      -- .settings/
      -- .project
      -- .classpath
```

From what I've read in the web, I don't need to add the .metadata directory to the repository. Also, I know I could have dependency problems in some situations if I add the .classpath folder to the repository, but I prefer to not support these problematic situations (eg different Java compilers) than forcing the dev to manually set the classpath. Finally, I don't want to use Maven in this project.

Concisely, my requirements are
- I don't want to put Eclipse project files in the root folder
- I don't want to duplicate the code inside eclipse folder (that's what happens when I try to import existing code into an isolated project folder). I want it to reference the source files I have in the folder named 'src'
- I want to configure Eclipse to put the compilation output (.class files) in the 'bin' folder.

That latter item I was able to set when creating the project, but I wasn't able to configure Eclipse to reference the source code (not duplicate it) without choosing a source parent directory as the project folder.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid putting .project, .classpath and .settings at the root?  Just so that the NetBeans users don't see them?

Comment: 1) I want to keep the minimum number of files at the root to avoid clutter and 2) I'd like to keep Eclipse-specific files isolated in a directory (it's not obvious to everyone that .project, .settings, etc refer to Eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a project in the place you want it, and then use 'linked source' directories to point to your actual source code.

more information:

[Store eclipse .project files outside the project directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422261/store-eclipse-project-files-outside-the-project-directory)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your directory structure above with the eclipse subdirectory.
2. Create a new Dynamic Web Application (or whatever, assuming based on .settings)
3. Uncheck `Use default location` and specify your `eclipse` directory, hit Next
4. Remove the lone source folder
5. Leave `Generate web.xml...` unchecked
6. File > New > Folder and click Advanced>>
7. Use `Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)` to create src and bin directories that are linked to the top-level src and bin.
8. Right-click on the project and use File > New > Source folder to add the linked src folder with an output directory of bin
9. Move WebContent to WebContent.bak and create a new WebContent directory that is linked to the top level.
10. Move the contents of WebContent.bak to WebContent
11. Manually edit `eclipse/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` to change WebContent.bak to WebContent (is there a setting for this?  couldn't find it)
12. Refresh the project
13. Right-click the project and select Java EE Tools > Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub