# Eclipse project files vanish when unmounting a dynamic view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, clearcase, configuration-files, eclipse-project-file

I (unfortunately) have to use ClearCase for some code of mine. Now, I'm using a dynamic view, mounted at `/path/to/source`. The problem I'm facing is how setup *and maintain* an Eclipse project, so that I can work on the code using Eclipse CDT. You see, when I unmount the view (or leave the shell were the view is set-up with `ct setview` - the `.project`, `.cproject` files and `.settings` folder - disappear.

Can I somehow tell Eclipse to put them elsewhere than where it looks for the source? Or is there some other workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I somehow tell Eclipse to put them elsewhere than where it looks for the source?

Yes: it can be good practice with Eclipse (independently of ClearCase) to keep the Eclipse project metadata and the actual project sources separate (even though the project structure remains fixed, as [issue 78438](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=78438) illustrates).
I used to do so [through linked resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819639/6309), as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/300346/6309) (or [step-by-step here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11849100/6309)).

The idea is to have a linked resource (or even a simple symlink) to where your sources are (the dynamic view, which might or might not be present), while your actual Eclipse project is actually created in another folder (which is stable and persistent)